# Simplest way to host a domain name just so I can forward it to a WordPress blog?

Tags: wordpress, domain-name-system

I have a domain name, and a WordPress account.  The domain name isn't hosted anywhere at the moment.  I just want to set it up so that my WordPress blog uses the domain.  According to the WordPress help page on this issue, I have to do the following:

Update your domain’s name servers to the following. Make sure to remove any existing name servers that are already there.

```
NS1.WORDPRESS.COM
NS2.WORDPRESS.COM
NS3.WORDPRESS.COM
```

So, this is the only thing that I need a server for - if I even need a server at all?  Is there a really simple way I can do this for free?  Or for very cheap?

I'm a bit ignorant about this stuff: I do [Ruby on Rails](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruby_on_Rails) coding, but I don't get involved in the really technical stuff to do with servers and DNS and what have you.

Answer (score 7):

You don't need a server (that's what WordPress.com is for). You can change your DNS adresses from the domain registrar's site (the usually have an admin panel of some sort).

Comment: ah, i'd hoped that might be the case.  thanks!  will reply if i have any problems :)

Comment: Don't forget that if you do this your domain name can _only_ be used for Wordpress.  E-mail or anything else for the domain won't work.